# Combining two tables and filtering only last date

Tags: sql-server, datefilter

I am attempting to combine two tables.  What I am attempting to find is if a person has an active plan or not.  It is something that the person can sign up for and discontinue.

From Table One, `Persons`, I am these columns:

```
PerID    FacID
 993     Fac1
1052     Fac1
1163     Fac2
```

From Table Two, `PlanDates`, I am these columns:

```
PerID   FacID   StartDt                     EndDt
 993    Fac1    2017-07-01 00:00:00.000     2017-07-31 00:00:00.000
 993    Fac1    2017-08-05 00:00:00.000     NULL
1053    Fac1    NULL                        NULL
1163    Fac2    2017-08-01 00:00:00.000     NULL
```

I am running this Query

```
Select
  A.PerID
  ,A.FacID
  ,B.PerID
  ,iif(CASE WHEN B.StartDt IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END = 'True', iif(CASE WHEN B.EndDt IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END = 'False', 'Plan A', 'None'),'None') AS [Plan Code]
  ,B.FacID
From
  Persons A
  Left Join PlanDates B
    On A.PerID = B.PerID
    And A.FacID = B.FacID
```

The results I get are:

```
PerID   Plan Code
 993    None
 993    Plan A
1052    None
1163    Plan A
```

I am looking to not have the first result for PerID 993.

The reason I have that iif statement in the query is to make the dates Boolean.

I included the FacID because some PerIDs are at multiple locations when a person visits moves closer to another location.

I am running the query on SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this gives the results you're looking for...

```
SELECT 
    p.PerID,
    p.FacID,
    PlanCode = CASE 
                    WHEN EXISTS (               
                                SELECT 
                                    1
                                FROM 
                                    dbo.PlanDates pd
                                WHERE 
                                    p.PerID = pd.PerID
                                    AND p.FacID = pd.FacID
                                    AND pd.StartDT IS NOT NULL 
                                    AND pd.EndDt IS NULL )
                    THEN 'Plan A'
                    ELSE 'None'
                END
FROM
    dbo.Person p;
```

Comment: That looks like it did exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Glad I could help. :)